# Angular directive load orders: Unknown Provider when used in Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a directive, `click-anywhere-but-here`, in my header HTML, using controller `navCtrl`. Angular is throwing error:

> Unknown provider: clickAnywhereButHereProvider <-

I'm thinking this has to do with how I'm using `gulp` to concatenate the JS files. I checked the concatenated `main.js` files with all JS, and see that `navCtrl` is defined above the `clickAnywhereButHere` directive. Not sure if this matters at all since the controller isn't using the directive at all, only the `header.html` file.

```
<header ng-controller="navCtrl">
  <a click-anywhere-but-here="clickedSomewhereElse()" ng-click="clickedHere()">
    <li>study</li>
  </a>
</header>
```

How can I force the header to wait until `clickAnywhereButHere` directive is loaded before complaining?

---

**Edit**: Code:

`navCtrl.js`: I've gutted out a lot of the unrelated code

```
angular
    .module('DDE')
    .controller('navCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$location', '$scope', 'Modal', 'Auth', '$window', '$state', 'deviceDetector',
        function($rootScope, $location, $scope, Modal, Auth, $window, $state, deviceDetector) {

            $scope.clicked = '';
            $scope.clickedHere = function(){
                $scope.clicked = 'stop that';
                console.log('clicked on element');
            };
            $scope.clickedSomewhereElse = function(){
                console.log('clicked elsewhere');
                $scope.clicked = 'thanks';
            };

            $scope.headings = [
                {page: 'contact', route: '#/contact'}
            ];
        }
    ]);
```

`clickAnywhereButHere.js` directive:

```
angular.module('DDE')
.directive('clickAnywhereButHere', function($document, clickAnywhereButHereService){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var handler = function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            };
            elem.on('click', handler);

            scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
                elem.off('click', handler);
            });

            clickAnywhereButHereService(scope, attr.clickAnywhereButHere);
        }
    };
});
```

`clickAnywhereButHereService.js` Service:

```
angular.module('DDE')
.factory('clickAnywhereButHereService', function($document){
    var tracker = [];

    return function($scope, expr) {
        var i, t, len;
        for(i = 0, len = tracker.length; i < len; i++) {
            t = tracker[i];
            if(t.expr === expr && t.scope === $scope) {
                return t;
            }
        }
        var handler = function() {
            $scope.$apply(expr);
        };

        $document.on('click', handler);

        // IMPORTANT! Tear down this event handler when the scope is destroyed.
        $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
            $document.off('click', handler);
        });

        t = { scope: $scope, expr: expr };
        tracker.push(t);
        return t;
    };
});
```

Both the directive and service are present in my `min` file:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us `navCtrl`?

Comment: @mparnisari added above

Comment: It sounds as if `clickAnywhereButHereService` is not present in your .min file

Comment: @mparnisari plz see above edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account the fact that [your JS is minified](https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification).

So change this

```
.directive('clickAnywhereButHere', function($document, clickAnywhereButHereService){
```

to this

```
.directive('clickAnywhereButHere', 
  ['$document', 'clickAnywhereButHereService', 
  function($document, clickAnywhereButHereService){ 
   //... 
  }])
```

Comment: easier to use `gulp ngInject`...saves manually creating dependency array